# How to increase the upload files limit of 15mb in nativescript sidekick while running tns preview?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, sidekick

I am trying to preview an app on my mobile device with Nativescript Sidekick using the Preview App option. I have scanned the QR code shown using the Playground app in my mobile. A warning is shown with the following message

> [19-11-02 05:33:25.361] (CLI) The files to upload exceed the maximum allowed size of 15MB. Your app might not work as expected.

And the app fails to load in live on my mobile
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: That sounds like a limitation intentionally made, Playground was designed to run quick samples / share and debug code easily. You may report it on [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/playground-feedback) though.